# Jquery function executes only once after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

As shown below: I want to trigger the function `doneTyping()` after the user is done typing (wait for 2 seconds) but it gets triggered only after I load the page for the first time or hit refresh. In case I change the contents in the textbox ResidentialZipCode multiple times, it doesn't work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var typingTimer; //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 2000;
    //on keyup, start the countdown
    function checkForChange() {
        debugger;
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if ($('#Residential_txt').val) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    }
    function doneTyping() {
        //do something
    }
    $("#Residential_txt").on('input change paste cut', checkForChange);
}
```

Any pointers on what needs to be rectified?

Comment: `#.val()` A method, not a property. | Should also fix the issue as the undefined property `#.val` will return "undefined" and thus fail the if statement as falsey.

Comment: TIP: Declare your `checkForChange()` and `doneTyping()` functions outside the `jQuery document ready handler`.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle to test with?

Comment: @KodleeYin Yin thanks, but the problem remains!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/C2Z38/

Comment: @KodleeYin `val` will not be undefined, it is a function which is truthy.

Comment: You're handling events on the element with id `Residential_txt` and your function is testing another one, with id `ResidentialZipCode_txt`. Is that correct or just a typo? Or you actually have more than one `input` and want to check all of them?

Comment: @MelanciaUK just a typo , sorry corrected it

Comment: So, this should be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/C2Z38/4/

Comment: The solutions so far ,unfortunately dont work for me Let me add one bit of detail that i missed , ResidentialZipCode_txt is what i picked from the rendered html , it is actually not a part of the page but rather a partial control named zip city state control

Answer (score -1):

`val` is a function, not a property. So try changing

```
if ($('#ResidentialZipCode_txt').val) {
```

to

```
if ($('#ResidentialZipCode_txt').val()) {
```

Comment: In the OP's code he is not using `val` as a function so what you're saying is not true. Also, the function is not going to be "truthy" if the value is empty or null.

Comment: @Nicholas `$("...").val` will **return** (not call) the function itself.  The function is truthy.